# Ingesting and LINE BREAKING json data to SPLUNK

Tags: arrays, json, rest, line-breaks, splunk

Looking to ingest this RESTAPI data to SPLUNK, but having issues with LINE BREAKER, can't seem to discover the correct combination for props.conf.

Also as data is returned in array format without keys, do I need a script to add the keys to the returned array data or can this be achieved using SPLUNK?

N.B.
The keys are returned in the tail of the response.

RESTAPI CALL:

```
{{base_url}}accounts/{{account}}/{{siteid}}/report?dimensions=queryName,queryType,responseCode,responseCached,coloName,origin,dayOfWeek,tcp,ipVersion,querySizeBucket,responseSizeBucket&metrics=queryCount,uncachedCount,staleCount,responseTimeAvg&limit=2
```

Any help appreciated.

```html
{
  "result": {
    "rows": 100,
    "data": [
      {
        "dimensions": [
         "college.edu",
          "A",
          "REFUSED",
          "uncached",
          "EWR",
          "192.0.0.0",
          "1",
          "0",
          "4",
          "48-63",
          "48-63"
        ],
        "metrics": [
          1,
          1,
          0,
          16
        ]
      },
      {
        "dimensions": [
          "school.edu",
          "A",
          "REFUSED",
          "uncached",
          "EWR",
          "192.0.0.0",
          "1",
          "0",
          "4",
          "32-47",
          "32-47"
        ],
        "metrics": [
          1,
          1,
          0,
          10
        ]
      }
    ],
    "data_lag": 0,
    "min": {},
    "max": {},
    "totals": {
      "queryCount": 12,
      "responseTimeAvg": 37.28936572607269,
      "staleCount": 0,
      "uncachedCount": 2147541
    },
    "query": {
      "dimensions": [
        "queryName",
        "queryType",
        "responseCode",
        "responseCached",
        "coloName",
        "origin",
        "dayOfWeek",
        "tcp",
        "ipVersion",
        "querySizeBucket",
        "responseSizeBucket"
      ],
      "metrics": [
        "queryCount",
        "uncachedCount",
        "staleCount",
        "responseTimeAvg"
      ],
      "since": "2022-10-17T04:37:00Z",
      "until": "2022-10-17T10:37:00Z",
      "limit": 100
    }
  },
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the JSON object to be a single event, the LINE_BREAKER setting should be `}([\r\n]+){`.

Splunk should have no problems parsing the JSON, but I think there will be problems relating metrics to dimensions because there are multiple sets of data and only one set of keys.  Creating a script to combine them seems to be the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply RichG, unfortunatley it didn't break them up, ended up printing the script to csv.